# Swift - Pattern Matching with Commutativity

Tags: swift, enums, pattern-matching, expression, commutativity

## Swift - Pattern Matching Enums with Associated Value with Commutativity

### Swift 5.0, Xcode 10.2.1

I have an `Expression` enum in Swift.

```swift
enum Expression {
    indirect case add(Expression, Expression)
    indirect case subtract(Expression, Expression)
    indirect case multiply(Expression, Expression)
    indirect case divide(Expression, Expression)
    indirect case power(Expression, Expression)
    indirect case log(Expression, Expression)
    indirect case root(Expression, Expression)
    case x
    case n(Int)
}

extension Expression: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Expression, rhs: Expression) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.add(a, b), .add(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.subtract(a, b), .subtract(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.multiply(a, b), .multiply(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.divide(a, b), .divide(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.power(a, b), .power(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.log(a, b), .log(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.root(a, b), .root(c, d)) where a == c && b == d:
            return true
        case let (.n(a), .n(b)) where a == b:
            return true
        case (.x, .x):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

---

### First Attempt

I perform a lot of pattern matching on my `Expression` type. The commutativity of addition and multiplication made for much long pattern matching expressions. I wanted to find a way to simplify and shorten this, so I decided to make an `ExpressionPattern` enum and define an overload of the pattern matching operator (`~=`).

```swift
enum ExpressionPattern {
    case commutativeMultiply(Expression, Expression)
    case commutativeAdd(Expression, Expression)
}

func ~= (lhs: ExpressionPattern, rhs: Expression) -> Bool {
    switch lhs {
    case let .commutativeMultiply(a, b):
        switch rhs {
        case .multiply(a, b), .multiply(b, a):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }

    case let .commutativeAdd(a, b):
        switch rhs {
        case .add(a, b), .add(b, a):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    default:
        return false
    }
}
```

I want to be able to replace pattern matching statements like:

```swift
case let .add(.n(3), a), let .add(a, .n(3)) where a > 10: //matches (a + 3), (3 + a)
//...
```

With:

```swift
case let .commutativeAdd(.n(3), a) where a > 10: //matches (a + 3), (3 + a)
//...
```

When I tried to do this for the first time though, I got an error say "Pattern variable binding cannot appear in an expression".

**Note:** I am that this match works if I use the exact, final values without value binding, but I utilize this feature in many places throughout my project.

#### Attempt Usage:

```swift
let expression: Expression = Expression.add(.divide(.n(1), .n(2)), .subtract(.n(3), .n(4)))
switch expression {

case let .commutativeAdd(.subtract(a, b), .divide(c, d)): //Error: Pattern variable binding cannot appear in an expression.
    print("This matches: ((\(a) - \(b)) + (\(c) ÷ \(d))) and ((\(c) ÷ \(d) + (\(a) - \(b)))")

default: 
   break

}
```

---

### Second Attempt

For my second attempt I changed the definition of `Expression`'s `==` function, and tried to override its default implementation of `~=`.

```swift
extension Expression: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Expression, rhs: Expression) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case let (.add(a, b), .add(c, d)) where  (a == c && b == d) || (a == d && b == c),
             let (.subtract(a, b), .subtract(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.multiply(a, b), .multiply(c, d)) where  (a == c && b == d) || (a == d && b == c),
             let (.divide(a, b), .divide(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.power(a, b), .power(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.log(a, b), .log(c, d)) where a == c && b == d,
             let (.root(a, b), .root(c, d)) where a == c && b == d:
            return true
        case let (.n(a), .n(b)) where a == b:
            return true
        case (.x, .x):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }

    static func ~= (lhs: Expression, rhs: Expression) -> Bool {
        return lhs == rhs
    }
}
```

### Attempt Usage:

```swift
let expression: Expression = Expression.add(.divide(.n(1), .n(2)), .subtract(.n(3), .n(4)))
print(expression == .add(.subtract(.n(3), .n(4)), .divide(.n(1), .n(2)))) //Prints "true"

switch expression {
case .add(.subtract(.n(3), .n(4)), .divide(.n(1), .n(2))):
    print("Matched")
default:
    print("Not matched")
}

//Prints "Not matched"
```

**Note:** This should have ideally printed "Matched".

---

### Question

How do I find a way to use full-fledged pattern matching while taking into account commutativity of certain cases.

**Note:** This must be able to be used for matching nested cases with commutativity (i.e. `.add(.multiply(..., ...), ...)`). This is especially important as a lot more cases are needed when matching something with both addition and multiplication.

Answer (score -1):

I changed your second usage as below

```
switch expression {
case let e where e == .add(.subtract(.n(3), .n(4)), .divide(.n(1), .n(2))):
    print("Matched")
default:
    print("Not matched")
}
```

I think it will work.

Comment: That does not allow me to use the wildcard pattern (underscore) or do any value-binding (which I rely heavily on) during the pattern matching.